# How to coordinate speed between streams in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I have a raw log stream and an algorithm stream like below.

[image]

As shown above, because the algorithm has windows, it takes a long time to produce results.The raw log stream run too fast, resulting in the output of the algorithm stream being discarded because it is far behind the watermark.

Thanks for any advice in advance!

Comment: Which Flink version are you using? Flink's watermark propagation mechanism should ensure that operators that connect two streams operate on the "slower" event time. So, records of the faster stream would be buffered until the time of the slower stream reaches a point at which they can be processed.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround.

According to [document](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/libs/cep.html#handling-lateness-in-event-time), elements will be buffered in CEP to wait watermark.

So I decide to change watermark generate strategy like below.

```
public class UnionStreamTimestampExtractor implements AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks<JSONObject> {
private long currentMaxTimestamp;
private boolean hasAlgoRule;

public UnionStreamTimestampExtractor(boolean hasAlgoRule) {
    this.hasAlgoRule = hasAlgoRule;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Watermark getCurrentWatermark() {
    return new Watermark(currentMaxTimestamp);
}

@Override
public long extractTimestamp(JSONObject element, long previousElementTimestamp) {
    long timestamp = element.get("occur_time") == null ?
            element.getLong("timestamp") : element.getLong("occur_time");
    // if this entity has algorithm rule
    // let anomaly slice generate watermark, so that CEP can buffer raw log data to wait them.
    if (hasAlgoRule) {
        if (element.containsKey("tensor")) {
            currentMaxTimestamp = Math.max(timestamp, currentMaxTimestamp);
        }
    } else {
        currentMaxTimestamp = Math.max(timestamp, currentMaxTimestamp);
    }

    return timestamp;
}
}
```

But it still have a problem, elements will be so many if streams have very different speed.